# How to change data of a corpus to appropriate format for training with 'caret' package in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, r-caret, text-classification, document-classification

**Q-1. How to change data of a corpus to appropriate format for training with 'caret' package?**

First of all, i would like to give you some environments for this question and i will be show you where i am stuck.

**Environments**

> This is corpus that is called `rt`. (R Code)

```
require(tm)
require(tm.corpus.Reuters21578) # to load data
data(Reuters21578)
rt<-Reuters21578
```

> And the training Document-Term-Matrix is created from training corpus called `dtmTrain`.
>   (R Code)

```
dtmTrain <- DocumentTermMatrix(rtTrain)
```

> I have totally 10 classes for this project. The classes are in the
>   metadatas of each document.

```
c("earn","acq","money-fx","grain","crude","trade","interest","ship","wheat","corn")
```

> I have created a data frame from rt which has (documents x classes). It is called
>   `docLabels`.

```
Docs  earn acq money-fx grain crude trade interest ship wheat corn
1    0   0        0     0     0     0        0    0     0    0
2    0   0        0     0     0     0        0    0     0    0
3    0   0        0     0     0     0        0    0     0    0
4    0   0        0     0     0     0        0    0     0    0
5    0   0        0     1     0     0        0    0     1    1
6    0   0        0     1     0     0        0    0     1    1
```

I assume that everything is clear so far.

**Problem**

*I have a document-term-matrix which has datas and a data frame which has classes as you can see. Eventually, How can i merge these two data objects for training with 'caret' package?*

**Q-2. How to train multiclass data with 'caret' package?**

*If we change the data appropriately, after that, how to train the data with caret package?*

This is from caret package documentation.

```
## S3 method for class 'formula'
train(form, data, ..., weights, subset, na.action, contrasts = NULL)
```

*So, what should be the form ?*

Comment: How did you create the DocumentxClasses data frame?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with matrices, you should consider the default method for `caret::train` rather than the formula interface.  Note under `?train` that you can pass the arguments like:

> **x**:     an object where samples are in rows and features are in columns.  This could be a simple **matrix**...
>
> **y**:     a numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample.

This will be simpler than building a formula.  So let's discuss how to obtain `x` and `y`.

**Getting x:**  We want to pass `caret::train` an x matrix with only those terms we want to use in the model.  So we have to narrow the `DocumentTermMatrix`, which is a sparse matrix, down to those terms:

```
# You need to tell people where to find the file so your example is reproducible
install.packages("tm.corpus.Reuters21578", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at")
library(tm.corpus.Reuters21578)
data(Reuters21578)
rt <- Reuters21578

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(rt)

# these are the terms you care about
your_terms <- c("earn","acq","money-fx","grain","crude","trade",
                "interest","ship","wheat","corn")

your_columns <- which(tolower(dtm$dimnames$Terms) %in% your_terms) # only 8 are found

your_dtm <- as.matrix(dtm[,your_columns]) # unpack selected columns of sparse matrix
```

**Getting y:**
Your question is not at all clear in terms of what your dependent variable is -- the thing you are trying to predict.  For this answer I will show you how to predict whether the document includes one or more uses of the word "debt."  If one of the classes in `your_terms` is actually your dependent variable, then remove it from `your_terms` and use it instead of "debt" in this example:

```
your_target <- as.integer(as.matrix(dtm[,'debt'])[,1] > 0) # returns array
```

**Training a model in `caret`.**

First we will create split the target vector and the explanatory matrix into 60/40 train/test sets.

```
library('caret')
set.seed(123)
train_rows <- createDataPartition(your_target, p=0.6) # for 60% training set

dtm_train <- your_dtm[train_rows,] 
y_train <- your_target[train_rows] 

dtm_test <- your_dtm[-train_rows,] 
y_test <- your_target[-train_rows]
```

Now you need to decide kind of model(s) you want to try.  For our example, we will use a lasso/ridge regression `glmnet` model. You should also try tree-based approaches such as `rf` or `gbm`.

Using the parallel backend is not strictly necessary but will speed up large jobs.  Feel free to try this example without it.

```
tr_ctrl <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=8, # train using 8-fold CV w/ 3 reps
                        repeats=3, returnResamp='none') 
library(parallel)
library(doParallel) # if using Windows, but for Linux/OSX use library(doMC) instead
use_cores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(use_cores)
  registerDoParallel(cl) # if using Windows, but for Linux/OSX use registerDoMC(cl)
  set.seed(123)
  glm <- train(x = dtm_train, y = y_train,         # You can ignore the warning about 
                  method='glmnet', trControl = t_ctrl)#  classification vs. regression.  
stopCluster(cl)
```

Of course there is a lot more tuning you could do here.

**Testing the model.**  You can use AUC here.

```
library('pROC')
auc_train <- roc(y_train, 
                 predict(glm, newdata = dtm_train, type='raw') )
auc_test <- roc(y_test, 
                 predict(glm, newdata = dtm_test, type='raw') )
writeLines(paste('AUC using glm:', round(auc_train$auc,4),'on training/validation set',
                 round(auc_test$auc,4),'on test set.'))
```

Running this I get `AUC using glm: 0.6389 on training/validation set 0.6552 on test set`.  So make sure to try other models and see if you can improve performance.

Comment: I forgot to put `family="binomial"` in the example `train()`.  You would probably get a better AUC by adding that parameter & treating this as a logistic rather than linear regression.